# Bootable USB with EaseUS that can recover from NTFS volume

Tags: usb, boot, hard-drive-recovery

I used EaseUS Todo Backup to backup my Win7 partition and then create WinPE bootable emergency USB. However, once I boot from USB I cannot access my NTFS volume where I put my backup. Is there a way to make it see NTFS volumes?

Comment: You need to specify where your NTFS volume is, usb, internal, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just booted my Thinkpad from Todo 2.5.1 boot disk and it see's my NTFS usb drive.

Did you click the "Browse" button at the bottom? It will not show up automatically you have to browse to the drive letter and drill down for the backup file.

If you did use the browse button, reboot and try another usb port.